# Prevent underlying div from scrolling in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, mobile-safari

I have a `div` that is 100% height, 70% viewport height, and `overflow:scroll`.

Now I want to create an overlaying `div` which touch devices can use to scroll the whole page instead of the `div`.

[image]

I created a `div` with `position:absolute` and full page height. If Android users drag on this `div`, the whole page scrolls, like expected. However, on iOS7 the underlying `div` is scrolled, like the touch event goes right trough the `div`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ag7e2/4/)

```
.scrollDiv{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    border:solid 1px #f00;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.pageScroller{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:50%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

If you use iOS7 and drag on the page `div` over the scrolling `div`, the scrolling `div` is scrolled instead of the page.

Does anybody know a solution for this?

Comment: Post a fiddle with your code in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On your `.pageScroller` scroller element, add the `overflow-y: scroll;` and `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` attributes, together with a postive `z-index`. That prevents the scroll action to reach the "layer" beneath.

```
.pageScroller{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:50%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    overflow-y:scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Check this JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R9Ut6/